# Umbraco Audio insert macro

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have some code from an older version (version 6) of umbraco that allows the user to choose an audio file and then insert a html 5 audio player into the page using a macro. I have copied this over to version 7 but it doesn't work. I keep getting this error :

Error loading Partial View script (file: ~/Views/MacroPartials/InsertAudio.cshtml)

Code :

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@{
                var controls = Parameter.controls;
                var mp3Url = Library.NodeById(Parameter.mp3).Url;
                string controlsTog = "";

if (controls == "1"){
                controlsTog = "controls";
}

<audio @controlsTog> 
                <source src="@mp3Url" type="audio/mpeg" /> 
Your browser does not support the audio tag. 
</audio>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your legacy razor macro to a Partial View Macro.  Here's a basic guide on how to perform the conversion:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/macros/Partial-View-Macros/

I've made the necessary changes to your script file but this is untested.  I've also assumed that your MP3 is an item in the Media section so if this is incorrect you might have to replace `Umbraco.TypedMedia` with `Umbraco.TypedContent`.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@{
    var mp3Id = Model.MacroParameters["mp3"].ToString();
    var mp3 = Umbraco.TypedMedia(mp3Id);
    var mp3Url = mp3 != null ? mp3.Url : string.Empty;
    var controlsTog = string.Empty;
    if (string.Equals(Model.MacroParameters["controls"].ToString(), "1"))
    {
        controlsTog = "controls";
    }
}

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mp3Url))
{
    <audio @controlsTog>
        <source src="@mp3Url" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Your browser does not support the audio tag.
    </audio>
}
```

Comment: I tried it both ways you suggested and keep getting the same error

Comment: @Jess - Any thoughts ?

Comment: I've just tested this locally and it worked for me.  Are your macro parameter aliases exactly they appear in the script?  In my case I have two parameters, one of type True/False with alias "controls" and one of type Single Media Picker with alias "mp3" (all lower case).  If the aliases are not correct then you'll get the "Error loading Partial View..." error.